# ConstraintLayout: Add UI elements programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to dynamically add a *new* ImageView below an *existing* XML-defined ImageView in a ConstraintLayout:

```
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

    ImageView imgAbove = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.topItemImg);
    ImageView imgBelow = new ImageView(this);
    imgBelow.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    imgBelow.setId(View.generateViewId());

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams imgAboveLayout = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) imgAbove.getLayoutParams();
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams imgBelowLayout = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(imgAboveLayout);

    imgBelowLayout.topToBottom = imgAbove.getId();
    imgAboveLayout.bottomToTop = imgBelow.getId();

    layout.addView(imgBelow);
    imgBelow.setLayoutParams(imgBelowLayout);
    imgAbove.setLayoutParams(imgAboveLayout);
```

However, this places the new view on top of the existing view so that they perfectly overlap. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to add constraintSet programmatically.

Comment: Why can't I use ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams? I heard that both, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams and ConstraintSet could be used to dynamically add to ConstraintLayouts, but that using LayoutParams is more efficient since it doesn't require cloning the whole existing layout for all views.

Comment: Params can be used when your build it from scratch programmatically, but you're having already one view ! so use ConstraintSet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

ImageView imgAbove = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.topItemImg);
ImageView imgBelow = new ImageView(this);
imgBelow.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
imgBelow.setId(View.generateViewId());

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams imgAboveLayout = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) imgAbove.getLayoutParams();
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams imgBelowLayout = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(imgAboveLayout);
layout.addView(imgBelow);
imgBelow.setLayoutParams(imgBelowLayout);
imgAbove.setLayoutParams(imgAboveLayout);

// Clone your constraint layout to ConstraintSet.
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(layout);
set.connect(imgBelow.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, imgAbove.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
set.connect(imgBelow.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, imgAbove.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
set.connect(imgBelow.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, imgAbove.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
set.applyTo(layout);
```

Check out more from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).

> **Note here :**  *For building up constraints at run time, using **[`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet)** is recommended.*

Comment: I tried this, but same outcome. Also, why are you mixing LayoutParams with ConstraintSet? Shouldn't it be one or the other?